# Simultaneous nonzero solution

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $f(x,y,z)$ be a polynomial in variables $x,y,z$ over an algebraically closed field $k$. Let $a,b,c\in k$ satisfy $f(a,b,c)\neq0$.

Then does there exist $d\in k$ such that
$$f(a,b,d), f(b,d,c)\neq0?$$

Maybe I have to use that field is algebraically closed and hence infinite. But I am not able to apply it here.

Comment: Not always - take $k=\Bbb C$, $f(x,y,z)=x-z$, $a=0$, $b=1$, $c=1$. Now no matter what you pick for $d$, you get $f(b,d,c)=0$.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you :)